# Defaults for Highcharts graphs

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We are using [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com) for the graphs in a dashboard web app. We are craeting the graph objects in javaScript. Most of the graphs share similar options. E.g. one graph is created by something like this:

```
Highcharts.chart('boiler-temp', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Boiler temperatures'
    },         
    legend: { 
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    },
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Inner temperature'
        }
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'Outer temperature',
        },
        opposite: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    }],
    data: {
        rowsURL: dataUrl,
    },
    series: [{
        yAxis: 0,
    }, {
        yAxis: 1,
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
        connectNulls: true
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        fallbackToExportServer: false
    }
}
```

Another graph is created very similarly like this:

```
Highcharts.chart('boiler-temp', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Boiler pressure'
    },         
    legend: { 
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    },
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Inner pressure'
        }
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'Outer outer pressure',
        },
        opposite: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    }],
    data: {
        rowsURL: dataUrl,
    },
    series: [{
        yAxis: 0,
    }, {
        yAxis: 1,
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
        connectNulls: true
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        fallbackToExportServer: false
    }
}
```

For maintainability I would like to define a *default set of options* as

```
{
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    legend: { 
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    },
    yAxis: [{
    }, {
        opposite: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    }],
    series: [{
        yAxis: 0,
    }, {
        yAxis: 1,
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
        connectNulls: true
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        fallbackToExportServer: false
    }
}
```

and then, when I instantiate a graph, overwrite what changes. Is there a way to do this with Highcharts/JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using Highcharts global options - set of options to all charts on the same page.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  chart: {
    type: 'spline'
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
  },
  yAxis: [{}, {
    opposite: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  }],
  series: [{
    yAxis: 0,
  }, {
    yAxis: 1,
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      connectNulls: true
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    fallbackToExportServer: false
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ugsfoyeh/

**Docs:**

- https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-set-options#2

---

Another approach is to create a defaultOptions somewhere in your app and merge them with chart options using eg. `Highcharts.merge()`.

```
const defualtData = {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline'
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
  },
  yAxis: [{}, {
    opposite: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  }],
  series: [{
    yAxis: 0,
  }, {
    yAxis: 1,
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      connectNulls: true
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    fallbackToExportServer: false
  }
};

Highcharts.chart('boiler-temp1', Highcharts.merge(defualtData, {
  title: {
    text: 'Boiler temperatures'
  }
}));
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5epm4hqc/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.merge

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'm looking for! Thanks heaps. Will confirm it *Tuesday* when I'm back at the machine we do the dashboard development on.

Comment: Great to hear that;)

Comment: Works perfectly. `Highcharts.merge` does even a "deep" merge: If you have in your default options `{ legend: { layout: 'vertical', align: 'right', verticalAlign: 'middle' } }` and you marge this with `{ legend: { verticalAlign: 'top' } }` then the chart will get the attributes `layout: 'vertical', align: 'right'` still from the default options. That's cool! :-)